# JSON.parse returning undefined object

Tags: json, google-apps-script, battlenet-api

Blizzard just shut down their old API, and made a change so you need an apikey. I changed the URL to the new api, and added the API key. I know that the URL is valid.

```
var toonJSON = UrlFetchApp.fetch("eu.api.battle.net/wow/character/"+toonRealm+"/"+toonName+"?fields=items,statistics,progression,talents,audit&apikey="+apiKey, {muteHttpExceptions: true})
var toon = JSON.parse(toonJSON.getContentText())
```

JSON.pase returns just an empty object

```
return toon.toSorce() // retuned ({})
```

I used alot of time to see if i could find the problem. have come up empty. Think it has something to do with the "responce headers".

Responce headers: http://pastebin.com/t30giRK1 (i got them from dev.battle.net (blizzards api site)
JSON: http://pastebin.com/CPam4syG

Answer (score 0):

I think it is the code you're using. 
I was able to Parse it by opening the raw url of your pastebin JSON http://pastebin.com/raw/CPam4syG
And using the following code

```
var text = document.getElementsByTagName('pre')[0].innerHTML;
var parse = JSON.parse(text);
```

So to conclude I think it is the `UrlFetchApp.fetch` that's returning {}

Comment: Do you have any idea how to get UrlFetchApp.fetch to work?. I also concluded that it was a valid JSON.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not that familiar with that library

Answer (score 0):

So i found the problems:

1. I needed https:// in the URL since i found after some hours that i had an SSL error
2. If you just use toString instead of getContentText it works. Thow why getContentText do not work, i am not sure of.

Answer (score 0):

was same problem, this works for me *(dont forget to paste your key)*

```
var toonJSON = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://eu.api.battle.net/wow/character/"+toonRealm+"/"+toonName+"?fields=items%2Cstatistics%2Cprogression%2Caudit&locale=en_GB&apikey= ... ")
```